# How to express path for image file which is inside exectutable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

My image file is in the `src` folder.

```
lblNewLabel.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("src/images.jpg"));
```

The above code works fine for the Eclipse project, but when I run its executable jar, the image is missing. I think I am messing up the image file path.

Comment: Don't reference `src` ever

Comment: Are you sure that you're building images.jpg into the jar?  You can check by finding the jar and running "jar -xf yourjarnamehere.jar" and seeing if it comes out.

Comment: cmd responded: jar is not recognizable as internal or external command. I can not run according to your advice.

Comment: Is this jar exe file? I can not find much info about it from internet.

Comment: I created resource folder in my project and put my image file there. The result same. I can load the image from eclipse IDE, but can not from executable jar.

Comment: I think that I have to use getClass().getResource(). But I do not know how to use it in the situation.

Comment: If we don't know where your images are in the file, we can't help. Find where the JDK is on your machine, install one if you haven't one, and execute `<JDK_PATH>/bin/jar tvf yourjar.jar`.

Comment: 0 Sun Mar 29 11:26:52 CDT 2015 org/eclipse/wb/
     0 Sun Mar 29 11:26:52 CDT 2015 org/eclipse/wb/swt/
 11089 Sun Mar 29 11:26:52 CDT 2015 org/eclipse/wb/swt/SWTResourceManager.class
 10148 Sat Sep 13 15:44:20 CDT 2014 images.jpg

Comment: Yes. images.jpg is inside the jar file.